# CSS Dropdown not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

I need some help.

I am optimizing a homepage i made for a registered association.

I want to support IE8 and IE7.

I am using a Dropdown navigation. If I hover on "Verein" a dropdown menu should slide down with the content "Vorstand, Satzung, ...".

Now here is my problem:
The dropdown is working in IE9, IE10, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But if I hover on "Verein" in IE8 the submenu wont slide down. It seems to be invisible.

I know its alot of code so I made a jsFiddle example (reduced code) like millimoose suggested:
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uPLSD/)

The jsFiddle works fine for me in IE7 so I believe its some css relevant stuff.

Here a live example of the site: [geschichtsverein-bademstal.de](http://geschichtsverein-bademstal.de)

Here the html structure:

```
<section id="navigation">
    <!-- Navigation Oben -->    
    <div id="navigation_bg"></div>
    <ul id="nav" class="nav">
        <li class="kontakt"><a href="#">Top</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Here my CSS:

```
ul.nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: -260px 10px 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; /* IE 8 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* IE 5-7 */
  z-index: 200;
}

ul.nav li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

/* Text Navileiste */
ul.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 10px 5px 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.nav li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.nav li:hover a {
  color: #000000;
}

/* Dropdown Navileiste */
ul.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 9999;
}

ul.nav ul li {
  float: none;
}

/* Text Dropdown Navileiste */
ul.nav ul a {
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 140px;
}

/* Hovereffekt */
ul.nav ul li:hover > a {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; /* IE 8 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* IE 5-7 */
}

/* Dropdown > Ebene 1 */
ul.nav ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4C4C4C;
}

/* Pfeilsymbol Dropdown */
ul.nav span {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.nav ul span {
  background-image:url("../../img/icons/arrowsub.png");
}
```

And here the JS:

```
    /* Subnav Ebene 1 */
$('.nav').children('li').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).find('.sub').slideDown(300);
    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).find('.sub').stop(true,true).hide();
    });
});

/* Subnav Ebene 2*/
$('.nav li ul').children('li').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).find('.sub_2').slideDown(300);
    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).find('.sub_2').stop(true,true).hide();
    });
});

/* Subnav Ebene 3 */
$('.nav li ul ul').children('li').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).find('.sub_3').slideDown(300);
    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).find('.sub_3').stop(true,true).hide();
    });
});
```

EDIT:
Solved my problem

Just deleted following Code in my css and now its working.

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; /* IE 8 */  
filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* IE 5-7 */
```

Thanks for every helpfull comment!

Comment: What is the problem then? Is all this code relevant to the one problem? (If not, provide a reduced code sample.) What steps have you done to diagnose this? (E.g. is there anything in the browser's error console?)

Comment: (Also: it is my impression that people generally won't go and debug your live site.)

Comment: The code provided is all used by the dropdown menu. I dont know whats causing this trouble therefore i posted the whole code. I am using IE build in Diagnostics tool and all I can see is a problem with the timeline.js. But its not relevant to my problem. For every other browser Firefox, Chrome, Safari its working fine. I tried to change the css so that the submenus arent disabled (deleted display: none) but the submenu wont show up.

Comment: "I don't know whats causing this trouble therefore I posted the whole code." - then your problem is that you can't diagnose your own problems. As a start, try deleting/simplifying code until the problem goes away. When it does, obviously what you just changed is somehow guilty. Posting all your code is a great way to get nobody to look at any of it.

Comment: Also, "is working fine" and "won't show up" are really vague descriptions. When's it supposed to show up? Can you make a jsFiddle with just a simple example of the problem? (I.e. use fake data, don't use multiple menu items per level of nesting, leave out any decorative CSS.)

Comment: Yeah hard to descripe. I made a JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/uPLSD/ .Thanks for this advice now I know that its working in IE7 too. So it could be some css related stuff.

Comment: I can't see any difference in behaviour in the fiddle between IE8 (IE9 set to IE8 mode using the console) and Chrome. I'm not sure how anyone is supposed to answer this question without a clear description of what about it is wrong.

Comment: I edited my first post hopefully now its clear enough. JSFiddle example is working for me in IE8 too. I cleared the code but its the same I am using on the homepage. But its not working on the homepage for me in IE8

Comment: You should preferrably edit the fiddle so it actually shows your problem happening, but at least the description helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned a class of KONTAKT to your popout but I don't see it in the code above.

I refer to this line...

```
<li class="kontakt">
```

Its possible the problem could be in there?

Comment: this class is used to display an active status. Like if your in contact.html the background of the navigation tab Kontakt is red. I didnt post the code for it.

Comment: When I try it in my IE9 browser with the browser mode set to IE7 or IE8 and document standards mode (did not try in quirks mode), it works fine, only thing I noticed is that there is no opacity the bg color is solid also there are more than 2 items in the drop down that appears

Comment: Hey im working with virtual machines for testing sites. I dont like compatiblity modes sometimes they arent correct. The html given above is only an example strucutre to reduce code. But I found a solution. Just deleted the opacity code and now its working :)

Comment: Gosh thats a good idea, maybe I should dig out my windows XP CD and install a virtual machine too. I wasn't aware the compatibility mode doesn't always render correctly. Additionally maybe this link can help you retain your original design with opacity [http://test.unintentionallyblank.co.uk/transparent.html] Its done WITHOUT DX